# ArrayList can not add ArrayList, error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, arraylist

I have code as:

```
ArrayList[] arraylist=new ArrayList[2];
    arraylist[0].add("Ngyen");
    arraylist[0].add("Van");
    arraylist[0].add("Jone");

    arraylist[1].add(20);
    arraylist[1].add(40);
    arraylist[1].add(28);
    System.out.println(arraylist[0]);
    System.out.println(arraylist[1]);
```

i try add value by add method, when at runtime, have a java.lang.NullPointerException, somebody can help me for this.

Comment: The array you have create provides for 2 possible elements of type `ArrayList`, but does not initialise either of those slots, so they are `null`.  Respectfully, this is Java 101 basics

Comment: You are creating the array of ArrayList in your code and then assigning string values to 0 and 1st index of array without initializing those positions for an arraylist object. Its not right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ArrayList[] arraylist=new ArrayList[2];
```

This create an array named `arraylist` which can hold `2` `ArrayList` but not initialized yet means `arraylist[0]` and `arraylist[1]` is currently `null`. So `arraylist[0].add("Ngyen");` will give you `NullPointerException`.

An `ArrayList` of string can be initialized by the following:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Or you can try this:

```
arraylist[0]= new ArrayList();
arraylist[1]= new ArrayList();
arraylist[0].add("Ngyen");
...
```

[Run live.](http://ideone.com/B6JUh8)

Comment: - Thanks for explain, it's nice

Comment: @QuanNguyen, you are welcome. You may read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

Your first statement

```
ArrayList[] arraylist=new ArrayList[2];
```

allocates an array object that can reference two `ArrayList`(s). It doesn't *instantiate* those `ArrayList`(s). And [raw-types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) are a ***bad*** idea. But you *could* add something like,

```
ArrayList[] arraylist = new ArrayList[2];
arraylist[0] = new ArrayList();
arraylist[1] = new ArrayList();
```

And I get

```
[Ngyen, Van, Jone]
[20, 40, 28]
```

But the above has no type safety. As you added `String` and `Integer` instances to the two `List`(s).

Answer (score -2):

try this.

```
ArrayList[] arraylist=new ArrayList[2]; // creating an array to hold two array list.

// these two statements got missed while copy and paste from my Editor, Apologies for that. 
arraylist[0] = new ArrayList();
arraylist[1] = new ArrayList();

arraylist[0].add("Ngyen");
arraylist[0].add("Van");
arraylist[0].add("Jone");

arraylist[1].add(20);
arraylist[1].add(40);
arraylist[1].add(28);
System.out.println(arraylist[0]);
System.out.println(arraylist[1]);
```

Comment: it's my code and get a error

Comment: @QuanNguyen , Apologies, I was in hurry, missed two statements. Apologies for that..